# Down Down Menu CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

First post on Stackoverflow.  I am a relative beginner to web development and am currently redesigning my DJ website.

http://www.jameswinfield.co.uk/v2.html

Within the top-left menu, I want to have a div that drops down upon clicking the Events tab (to show the next event I am DJing at).

I have tried various ideas but none are working.

Please can you help.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 0):

Add these code to your Css . your .test div will be shown when you hover on its li .

```
.menu.top nav .test {display: none;}    
.menu.top nav li:hover .test {display: block;}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering however I wanted it to drop down on click, as opposed to hover.